# How to run Spark driver in HA mode?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, mesos

I have a Spark driver submitted to a Mesos cluster (with highly-available Mesos masters) in client mode (see [this](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-mesos.html) for `client` deploy mode).

I'd like to run the Spark driver in HA mode, too. How?

I can implement my own implementation for this, but for now looking for anything available.

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr** Use `cluster` deploy mode with `--supervise`, e.g. `spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster --supervise`

Having a HA of a Spark driver in `client` mode is not possible as [described in the cited document](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-mesos.html#client-mode):

> In client mode, a Spark Mesos framework is launched directly on the client machine and waits for the driver output.

You'd have to *somehow* monitor the process on the client machine and check its exit code perhaps.

A much safer solution is to let Mesos do its job. You should use `cluster` deploy mode in which it's Mesos to make sure the driver runs (and gets restarted when goes down). See the section [Cluster mode](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-mesos.html#cluster-mode):

> Spark on Mesos also supports cluster mode, where the driver is launched in the cluster and the client can find the results of the driver from the Mesos Web UI.

Comment: Hi Jacek, Can you please help me understand this line in the cluster mode - Note that the MesosClusterDispatcher not yet supports multiple instances for HA.

Comment: _"MesosClusterDispatcher not yet supports multiple instances for HA."_ I don't need that. A Spark driver is your Spark application's orchestrator and that's where your code becomes tasks. So, we assume a single instance of a Spark driver and only when it fails it will get resubmitted. Only one instance at a time.